# List<string> -> xml deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

I am having the following xml file :

```
<ItemList>
    <Item id="item-aa-00" status="TYPE1">
        <Elements>
            <element>element121</element>       
        </Elements>     
    </Item>
    <Item id="item-aa-01" status="TYPE2">
        <Elements>
            <element>element122</element>
            <element>element123</element>
            <element>element124</element>
        </Elements>     
    </Item> 
</ItemList>
```

I am trying to deserialize it using the following model :

```
[DataContract]
public enum ItemStatusEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "TYPE1")]
    TYPE1 = 10,
    [EnumMember(Value = "TYPE2")]
    TYPE2 = 20
}

[XmlRoot("Item")]
[DataContract(Name = "Item")]
public class ItemDto
{

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "candidateElements")]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<string> Elements { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Elements")]
    [XmlArrayItem("element"), Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public List<string> CandidateElementsSurrogate { get { return Elements .ToList(); } set { Elements = value; } }

    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "status")]
    public ItemStatusEnum Status { get; set; }

    public ItemDto()
    {
        this.Elements = new List<string>();
    }

}

[XmlRoot("ItemList")]
[DataContract(Name = "ItemListDto", Namespace = "")]
public class ItemListDto
{

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    [DataMember(Name = "myElements")]
    public List<ItemDto> myElements { get; set; }

}
```

This model manages to deserialize my xml file, but the Elements collection remains empty. What i am missing ?

Comment: Forgive me if I glossed over something but I don't see you adding anything to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed this two properties and could deserialize your xml:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public List<string> Elements { get; set; }

[XmlArray("Elements")]
[XmlArrayItem("element")]
public List<string> CandidateElementsSurrogate { get { return Elements; } set { Elements = value; } }
```

i have removed `DataMember` Attributes, they are not used by deserialization.

Comment: The reason why i use the CandidateElementsSurrogate is that i need to have Enumerbale<string> Elements { get; set; } and i want the deserializaton to use the surrogate in order to do it's job

Comment: I understood, in that case, you should ommit ToList and change Property typ to lost, i update my answer

Comment: it is not possible to have IEnumerable<string> Elements {get; set; } ?  even with List<string> Elements i have an empty "Elements" list

Comment: you need List to deserialize it. if you leave one property IEnumerable and one List, every time you call ToList() one new instance of the list will be created, serializer will add new item to it, and next time new empty instance will be used and so on